# How to trace SVN log for a particular file?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am having a situation with TortoiseSVN where I am not able to trace back the file that has been move to other directory. This is the process I move and commit the file:

1. I checkout the file locate in `path_A`.
2. copy the file to `path_B`.
3. delete the file in `path_A`.
4. commit both `path_A` and `path_B`.

When I bring up Log Message, I only able to see the log locate in `path_B` but the log before it were gone. Is there a way to trace back the log for a particular file?

Comment: Are you using the TortoiseSVN copy or the Windows explorer copy?

Comment: yes. But is the implementation is different between OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure by your comment what exactly you use to copy the file, but nevertheless:
You *must* use the TortoiseSVN copy/move function in order to retain the files history.

If you copy the file in any other way you are basically doing this behind SVNs back.
It cannot know that this file is actually a copy of another file.

If you use the TortoiseSVN function it tells the SVN server that `FileB` is a copy of `FileA` at revision `X` and it takes over its history.

If you are unsure how this is done, there is a good documentation at:
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-copy.html